# Xcode DMG for Snow Leopard consistently not mounting

Tags: xcode, osx-snow-leopard

I am running Snow Leopard 10.6.8 and attempting to install Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard. [(This one, the blue download link from the dev center).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O64zr.png)

However, the DMG always gives [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USJbN.png) error (not recognised) when I try to open it.

Does anyone have any experience with this problem? It seems odd that all other DMGs should work apart from this one. Could this mean my computer is incompatible with Xcode 4.2? Or, am I downloading the wrong one?

I hope this is an acceptable question for SO, as I hope someone has had and solved this problem. General Googling for an unrecognised DMG has yielded nothing but 'redownload DMG', which I have done three times already.

Many, many thanks.

Comment: Check the MD5sum of your DMG, it might have been corrupted during the download.

Comment: @Cyrille OK. How do I know what the MD5sum should be? And, I've downloaded it three times now. Could it really get corrupted all three times? Thanks.

Comment: What is the URL for the download page pictured in your first link? I know I've seen that before, but I can't find it anymore. Anyway, you might also try downloading Xcode from [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action). Maybe that will work better.

Comment: I have downloaded **Xcode 4.2** and **Xcode 4.2.1** as well from [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) using safari and chrome and I did it three times and in all cases I received **"not recognized"** error on both `Lion` and `Snow Leopard`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite downloading the DMG three times, I tried in Safari instead of Chrome as I had been doing and it working perfectly.

If anyone else has this similar 'DMG not recognised' error and finds their way here: try another browser.